How to use ipv6 proxies with seleniumbase
I am tasked to perform webscraping using seleniumbase Driver. for this i was given an ipv6 proxy in the form of a string matching the format
hypothetical_username:hypothetical_password@[2904:f777:0:10e:4433:6223:f5f2:59ee]:1234

But i am unable to apply it to the Driver and keep on getting errors regarding formats
the code in question is this
from seleniumbase import Driver
proxy="hypothetical_username:hypothetical_password@[2904:f777:0:10e:4433:6223:f5f2:59ee]:1234"
driver = Driver(browser="chrome", do_not_track=True, uc=True, block_images=True,uc_cdp=True, proxy=proxy)

The error i get is this
Exception: WARNING: Proxy String ["[2904:f777:0:10e:4433:6223:f5f2:59ee]:1234"] is NOT in the expected "ip_address:port" or "server:port" format, (OR the key does not exist in seleniumbase.config.proxy_list.PROXY_LIST).
I have tried removing the brackets from the ipv6 too but it is to no effect
hypothetical_username:hypothetical_password@2904:f777:0:10e:4433:6223:f5f2:59ee:1234

The code works perfectly with ipv4 but not ipv6

I think your best bet is asking Michael - https://github.com/mdmintz
